# Candidate for migration?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Regarding https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3696/can-charged-open-sourcing-be-a-viable-model-for-a-freelancer

I'm wondering if this is a candidate for migration to opensource.stackexchange.com

I know Amelia is on OS, and her answer here is good, but the OP may be able to get a wider variety of expert answers there.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: I had a chat with the opensource mods, and I've migrated the question over.

---

With a little bit of editing, it's certainly a decent, on-topic question for opensource (regarding commercial usage of open source licenses, and going into the open-source definition), but I'd say we should *probably* keep it. It's on-topic here according to the definition we have, so there's no harm in a little overlap.

I'm naturally biased because I've answered it, but I could float it by the open source mods. It would probably be well received there, but a better way to go about this would be to ask the same question but in a different context.

For example: *"Can I charge for a work under an open-source license?"*, etc.